# Как искать null значения в json поле

Tags: postgresql

Есть табличка с колонкой типа json. Мне нужно искать по этому полю по определенным полям, например найти все строки у которых `entity => 5`. Тут все просто. Пишем выборку с таким условием `field->>'entity' = '5'`.

Второй случай, это надо найти все строки, где вообще нет ключа entity. Тут тоже все просто. Условие `field->>'entity'` IS NULL

А как теперь объединить два эти случая, чтобы я в один и тот же скрипт передавал параметр, который равен либо 5, либо `null`? Может можно как-то по другому сравнить с нулом? = `null` не работает((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from some_table where field->'entity' = 'null'::jsonb;
```